# Is there a good reason why Apache’s Maven enforcer plug-in demands v.3.8.6?

Tags: maven

When studying a course on how to use the Jenkins CI tool I encountered an issue that 3.6.3 is the latest version that we can install, but Apache’s Maven enforcer plug-in demands 3.8.6.

Does anyone know why there is this discrepancy? Thank you.

I ran apt-get install maven in my command prompt, and was able to install maven 3.6.3.

"maven is already the newest version (3.6.3-5)"

The error message was:

[info] --- maven- clean- plugin: 2.5: clean. (default- clean) @ my- app ---
[info] --- maven- enforcer- plugin: 3.1.0: enforce (enforce- maven) @ my-app ---
[Error] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion failed with message: Detected Maven version 3.6.3 is not in the allowed range [3.8.6).

Presumably there is a version 3.8.6 out there somewhere if the plug-in enforcer expects one.

Comment: How you discovered that enforcer plugin require Maven 3.8.6?

Comment: But https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/plugin-info.html says at least Maven 3.2.5 is required, not 3.8.6. Are you using a specific enforcer rule, that requires Maven 3.8.6?

Comment: Please add your pom file ... and also the log output...

Comment: I've added an image of the error message. Thank you for your questions, I'm a newbie, I'm not aware of using an enforcing rule myself, I rather thought that one was being imposed upon me. :-) I don't know where to find a POM, sorry.

Comment: The system rejected my image, sorry.

Comment: I have seen https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html and I'm now thinking that this issue may not be a generally experienced one, but something associated with this study project.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for directing my attention to the POM! Therein lies the issue! The Maven plugin enforcer lies within the POM. I have updated it from 3.8.6 to 3.6.3. Thank you for leading me to the answer.

```html
<rules>
            <requireMavenVersion>
            <version>[3.8.6,)</version>
            </requireMavenVersion>
            <requireJavaVersion>
              <version>[11,)</version>
            </requireJavaVersion>
          </rules>
```